# Timestamp when message was received by RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

How do I get a timestamp for when a message was received by RabbitMQ? In our application, we would like to measure how long a message was in the queue:

```
time_in_queue=System.currentTimeMillis() - timestamp_from_msg
```

Comment: Why not simply adding timestamp to the header of the message when you publish it.

Comment: I need only time spent in RabbitMQ. Network latency will be exclude (customer send a message, RabbitMQ get the message and add the timestamp and I can measure the time in RabbitMQ). Also netowork latency can be measured when the server time (client, RabbitMQ, server app) will be synchronized.

Answer (score 5):

I updated the "rabbitmq-message-timestamp" plugin. My change was merged and it is possible to use the new header "timestamp_in_ms" which contains timestamp in milliseconds.

Answer (score 2):

There's the [rabbitmq_message_timestamp](https://www.rabbitmq.com/community-plugins.html) plugin that does that:

> A plugin that adds a timestamp when a
>   message first enters RabbitMQ.
>
> Author: Team RabbitMQ
>
> Github: rabbitmq/rabbitmq-message-timestamp

Comment: Yep, but problem is, that the timestamp contains only seconds, not milliseconds. I created issue for this on GitHub. I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: @hradilf Did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

At least as of RMQ 5.10.0, it appears that there is a getTimestamp() method on the properties object returned with each message.

```java
public class ExchangeConsumer extends DefaultConsumer {
    ...
    @Override
    public void handleDelivery(String consumerTag,
                           Envelope envelope,
                           AMQP.BasicProperties properties,
                           byte[] body) throws IOException {
        Date timestamp = properties.getTimestamp();
    }
```